# how to arrange the widget based on left and top value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

From response data i am getting left, top, width, height, type and rotate values.
Based on that data we have to show the widget.

type 0 -> circle
type 1 -> square
type 2->  rectangle.

Based on left and top values we have to show the image on screen and we have to do rotation from rotation value.

Response:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "locationId": 2,
            "name": "Section 1",
            "tables": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "locationId": 2,
                    "sectionId": 3,
                    "orderId": 0,
                    "left": 469.206177,
                    "top": 108.030769,
                    "rotate": 315.0,
                    "width": 108.447479,
                    "height": 108.447479,
                    "seats": 4,
                    "type": 1,
                    "name": "Test 1",
                    "createdBy": 3,
                    "createdAt": "2021-03-16T16:42:21.397",
                    "updatedBy": 3,
                    "updatedAt": "2022-06-23T00:13:44.723"
                },
```

So I created the layoutwidget for three types of images (circle, square, rectangle).
First one is i am  applying rotation to container but it is not rotating.
Second one is how to add the widgets to screen. how it will move to second line based on left and top values.

layout_widget.dart:

```
class LayoutWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double left;
  final double top;
  final int type;
  final String name;
  final double rotate;

  LayoutWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.type,
    required this.left,
    required this.top,
    required this.name,
    required this.rotate,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LayoutWidgetState();
}

class _LayoutWidgetState extends State<LayoutWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(315),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: widget.left, top: widget.top),
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            borderRadius: widget.type == 0
                ? BorderRadius.circular(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5)
                : null),
        child: Center(child: Text(widget.name,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

page:

```
LayoutWidget(
                    width: 108.447479,
                    height: 108.447479,
                    type: 1,
                    left: 469.206177,
                    top: 108.030769,
                    name: 'Test 1',
                    rotate: 315.0,
                  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Stack with positioned widget to achieve your positioning of widgets, Positioned Widget provides top, left, bottom, right parameters to arrange widgets accordingly.

Use Transform.rotate widget to rotate widgets, it has an angle property which takes angles in radians so you'll have to adjust accordingly. (convert degrees to radians -> degrees*(3.14/180))

```
return Stack(
    children:[
        Positioned(
            top: $top-value
            left: $left-value
            child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: $angle-value*(3.14/180),
                child: Container(
                width: $width-value,
                height: $height-value,
                child: YourDesiredWidget(),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to pass the data to stack/postioned widget to from api. I will get top, right, left and rotate values from API.

Comment: Create a model of your json response for dart from here [link](https://app.quicktype.io/) and then you can pass the values from that model instance to the stack widget